# How to set wget timeout parameters?

Tags: curl, timeout, wget

I try to use function system() to call wget to grab some contents from a remote real-time data feeder, I set wget -T to 20 and set -t to 0, if I understand correctly, then that will allow Wget to abort if either the connect or read time exceeds 20 secs, without retries.

However, it seems that this doesnt work, when the net connection is bad, wget will simply hang there forever, so how could I suppose to do to avoid such situations?

Also, I heard it is possible some bugs there in this old version of wget(I am a mostly Windows user), I may try curl as well, can anyone tell me if curl handle timeout better?

Answer (score 0):

use the parameter

```
--read-timeout=SECS -t 0
```